# Как выполнить метод из Class Based Views по открытию страницы Django?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

пробую разобраться с CBV.
Хочу, чтобы функция test_http_response отрабатывалась как только выполняется запрос на урл, но она что то не работает. Подскажите, как правильно, пожалуйста.

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post
def test_http_response(self, request, pk):
    HttpResponse("test response")
    print("test")
```

Comment: попробуйте переименовать функцию test_http_response в get.

Comment: В этом случае работает, но тогда теряется базовая логика DetailView. Мне интересно реально ли в одном CBV реализовать несколько get методов для разделения логики внутри одного класса?

Comment: Я не пробовал, но судя по документации за это отвечает метод dispatch. Можно попробовать обрабатывать в нём исходный request и исходя из содержимого вызывать нужный метод get.